# How to check which ftl is used to render a page in a webapp built with Struts

Tags: struts2, freemarker

I was wondering if there is an easy way to find the ftl template currently in use on a web page.  How can I trace which ftl file is being used to generate that web page.

My web app is built using Struts

Thanks.

Comment: I need some more context around your situation.  Is your application built using a particular framework (i.e. Struts)?

Comment: yes, the application is built using spring and struts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, look at the URL of the page your viewing.  It should look something like "..localhost:8080/your-app/someAction.action".  The .action suffix is not required, but it is common.  It also doesn't have to be .action, it could be anything (i.e. '.do').

Now find your struts.xml.  That will be located on the classpath of your project.  Your struts.xml will contain Action tags, like this.

```
<action name="someAction,action" class="com.your.action.ActionClass">
    <result name="success"type="freemarker">/templates/some.ftl</result>
</action>
```

The end of the url of the page, is mapped to an action in here.  Look at the result returned from the action, and you find the FTL that is used to generate the response.

This is the best I can do, with the information you have provided.  Keep in mind this is a basic example, and most large apps have customized approaches, like spreading out the struts.xml to several different files, or using namespaces to divide actions into packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any common code that's included on all your pages (say a header or footer), you could temporarily add the following to it:

`Template: ${(stack.findValue("com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext.actionInvocation").result.location)!}`

Then view the page in a web browser.